# Combined text- and image-button, resizing drawable

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, resize, drawable

I have a button that I've implemented in one of my activities in my Android project - the button is supposed to contain both a logo (a drawable) and some text following it, but I have a very peculiar problem. In the preview-view of my activity xml-file, the button looks perfectly fine but when I run my app on my phone it gets absurdly large.

I import the drawable from an .xml drawable that I've myself have made. I tried imported a .png straight into my activity but it was too large - so I make a new xml where I resize it and *that* xml is what I import as my drawable. Code:

**Activity.xml**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title_activity_facebookInvite"
    android:id="@+id/btnInviteFacebook"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mainActivityInviteText"
    android:background="@drawable/bh_red_button"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/bh_input_element_margin"
    android:textSize="@dimen/bh_button_font_size"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/fb_resize"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
    android:minHeight="0dp" />
```

**fb_resize.xml (My drawable)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/fb_resizeBtn"
    android:drawable="@mipmap/fb_logo"
    android:width="15dp"
    android:height="15dp"
    />

</layer-list>
```

fb_logo is my PNG that I've made. Another very strange thing is that when I emulate it on a virtual device in Android Studio it looks perfectly fine, but not on my phone (Have tried a different phone aswell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! Instead of a .png I used a vector-picture (.svg file) and that resized just fine for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is your problem :

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Try replacing `fill_parent` with `wrap_content`

You could also try to add this in your item :

```
 android:scaleType="fitCenter"
 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Okay here is a workaround, try replacing your button with this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/NavigateRightButtonLayout"          
    android:layout_below="@+id/mainActivityInviteText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
     android:textSize="@dimen/bh_button_font_size"
     android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
     android:textAlignment="gravity"
     android:text="@string/title_activity_facebookInvite"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:background="@drawable/bh_red_button"
     android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/bh_input_element_margin"
     android:textSize="@dimen/bh_button_font_size"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
      <ImageView
       android:layout_width="15dp"
       android:layout_height="15dp"
       android:layout_gravity="left"
       android:id="@+id/fb_resizeBtn"
       android:background="@mipmap/fb_logo" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, tried your tip but it didn't really change much - it just made the button a bit narrower, but the logo size is still really large

Comment: Still doesn't work - I really can't see how this can be so hard to fix. Really thankful for your efforts though!

Comment: You're welcome ^^ If this one doesn't do the trick, well i'm out of ideas. If this doesn't work could you give us a picture of what happens and what is your expected result ?

Comment: After trying your xml code i can confirm that your drawable fb_resize.xml will never follow the width and height parameters and instead take as much space as it can. I don't know why though

Comment: Now it doesn't show the text nor the icon anymore, haha. This is really strange.

Comment: yep i forgot the text in the xml i gave you, i just edited it. For the icon try adding android:scaleType="fitCenter" and
 android:adjustViewBounds="true"  in the imageView i wrote above

Comment: Yea, I figured. Added the text myself aswell. Although now I don't see the button at all when I emulate it on my phone, and when I highlight the section in the activity.xml it's not on the button, it's a bit above it for some reason

Comment: Now I have to go sadly, but a big thanks to you for reaching out to help me - really appreciate it you're a hero. Hopefully I can solve it somehow when I sit down with it next time :) Cheers